# How do Bargmann-Fock-Segal spaces play an important role in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, complex-numbers

*An Advanced Complex Analysis Problem Book* by Daniel Alpay states on page 475:

> Bargmann-Fock-Segal spaces of analytic functions plays an important role in quantum mechanics; we refer for instance to the book Yurii Neretin.

I don't currently have access to this other resource by Neretin to exemplify this claim. How are Fock spaces are used in Quantum Mechanics?

Comment: It's actually stated right in the corresponding Wikipedia page, they are used for describing many particle systems.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space

Comment: @Photon Careful - this isn't the many-body [Fock space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space), it's the [Segal-Bargmann(-Fock) space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal%E2%80%93Bargmann_space), perhaps better known to physicists as the "holomorphic representation" of c/a operators in some contexts.

Comment: I see, thanks for the comment!